# What does "!" do in a rewrite Rule?

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently looking at an htaccess file. It contains this content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|png|xml)$ index.php
```

What does the "!" do and is this a valid redirection for css and other critical files?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule It's about halfway down the `RewriteRule` docs section. Not easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` basically means `NOT`. In other words, as long as the following doesn't match, apply the rule.

```
# anything that does NOT end in .css, .jpg, .png, or .xml
# send to index.php    
RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|png|xml)$ index.php
```

Comment: What he said.. And, as I recall, you can control which part the NOT should target

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, it says if **not** those extensions then rewrite to index.php.

For this example,

```
RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|png|xml)$ index.php
```

this can also be written as

```
#if these file extensions don't do anything and stop processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|jpg|png|xml)$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#else send everything to php
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

So anyway you want to omit files you can do. However your rule is shorter. It's valid to answer your question so that certain files don't get routed to index.php.

Comment: this is interesting, can you tell me what the "-" in The first RewriteRule?

Comment: It just means to not do anything because there is no substitution string.